# Proving if n = m and m = o, then n + m = m + o in Idris?

Tags: proof, idris

I am trying to improve my Idris skill by looking at some of the exercises [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/toc.html) (originally for Coq, but I am hoping the translation to Idris not too bad). I am having trouble with the ["Exercise: 1 star (plus_id_exercise)"](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#lab31) which reads:

> Remove "Admitted." and fill in the proof.
>
> ```
> Theorem plus_id_exercise : ∀ n m o : nat,
>   n = m → m = o → n + m = m + o.
> Proof.
>   (* FILL IN HERE *) Admitted.
> ```

I have translated to the following problem in Idris:

```
plusIdExercise : (n : Nat) ->
                 (m : Nat) ->
                 (o : Nat) ->
                 (n == m) = True ->
                 (m == o) = True ->
                 (n + m == m + o) = True
```

I am trying to perform a case by case analysis and I am having a lot of issues. The first case:

```
plusIdExercise Z Z Z n_eq_m n_eq_o = Refl
```

seems to work, but then I want to say for instance:

```
plusIdExercise (S n) Z Z n_eq_m n_eq_o = absurd
```

But this doesn't work and gives:

```
When checking right hand side of plusIdExercise with expected type
        S n + 0 == 0 + 0 = True

Type mismatch between
        t -> a (Type of absurd)
and
        False = True (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                \uv => t -> uv
        and
                (=) FalseUnification failure
```

I am trying to say this case can never happen because n == m, but Z (= m) is never the successor of any number (n). Is there anything I can do to fix this? Am I approaching this correctly? I am somewhat confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would argue that the translation is not entirely correct. The lemma stated in Coq does not use boolean equality on natural numbers, it uses the so-called propositional equality. In Coq you can ask the system to give you more information about things:

```
Coq < About "=".
eq : forall A : Type, A -> A -> Prop
```

The above means `=` (it is syntactic sugar for `eq` type) takes two arguments of some type `A` and produces a *proposition*, not a boolean value.

That means that a direct translation would be the following snippet

```
plusIdExercise : (n = m) -> (m = o) -> (n + m = m + o)
plusIdExercise Refl Refl = Refl
```

And when you pattern-match on values of the equality type, Idris essentially rewrites terms according to the corresponding equation (it's roughly equivalent to Coq's `rewrite` tactic).

By the way, you might find the [Software Foundations in Idris](https://github.com/idris-hackers/software-foundations) project useful.