# What is the equivalent of propositional not equals?

Tags: idris

I somewhat recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50539825/667648) and resolved the issue with a some applications of the `rewrite` tactic. I then decided to look back at one of [my other questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/194585/82612) on code review asking for a review of my attempt to formalize Hilbert's (based on Euclid's) geometry.

From the first question, I learned there is a distinction between propositional equality and boolean equality and propositional equality. Looking back at the some of the axioms I wrote for the Hilbert plane, I utilized boolean equality extensively. Although I am not 100% sure, in light of the answer I received, I suspect that I don't want to use boolean equality.

For instance, take this axiom:

```
  -- There exists 3 non-colinear points.
  three_non_colinear_pts : (a : point ** b : point ** c : point ** 
                           (colinear a b c = False, 
                           (a /= b) = True, 
                           (b /= c) = True, 
                           (a /= c) = True))
```

I tried rewriting it to not involve the `= True`:

```
  -- There exists 3 non-colinear points.
  three_non_colinear_pts : (a : point ** b : point ** c : point ** 
                           (colinear a b c = False, 
                           (a /= b), 
                           (b /= c), 
                           (a /= c)))
```

All in all I took the code from my question on codereview removed the `==` and removed `= True`:

```
interface Plane line point where 
  -- Abstract notion for saying three points lie on the same line.
  colinear : point -> point -> point -> Bool
  coplanar : point -> point -> point -> Bool
  contains : line -> point -> Bool

  -- Intersection between two lines
  intersects_at : line -> line -> point -> Bool

  -- If two lines l and m contain a point a, they intersect at that point.
  intersection_criterion : (l : line) -> 
                           (m : line) ->
                           (a : point) ->
                           (contains l a = True) -> 
                           (contains m a = True) -> 
                           (intersects_at l m a = True)

  -- If l and m intersect at a point a, then they both contain a.
  intersection_result : (l : line) ->
                        (m : line) ->
                        (a : point) ->
                        (intersects_at l m a = True) ->
                        (contains l a = True, contains m a = True)

  -- For any two distinct points there is a line that contains them.
  line_contains_two_points : (a :point) -> 
                             (b : point) ->
                             (a /= b) ->
                             (l : line ** (contains l a = True, contains l b = True ))

  -- If two points are contained by l and m then l = m
  two_pts_define_line : (l : line) ->
                        (m : line) ->
                        (a : point) ->
                        (b : point) ->
                        (a /= b) ->
                        contains l a = True ->
                        contains l b = True ->
                        contains m a = True -> 
                        contains m b = True -> 
                        (l = m)

  same_line_same_pts : (l : line) ->
                       (m : line) ->
                       (a : point) ->
                       (b : point) ->
                       (l /= m) ->
                       contains l a = True ->
                       contains l b = True ->
                       contains m a = True ->
                       contains m b = True ->
                       (a = b)

  -- There exists 3 non-colinear points.
  three_non_colinear_pts : (a : point ** b : point ** c : point ** 
                           (colinear a b c = False, 
                           (a /= b), 
                           (b /= c), 
                           (a /= c)))

  -- Any line contains at least two points.
  contain_two_pts : (l : line) ->
                    (a : point ** b : point ** 
                    (contains l a = True, contains l b = True))

-- If two lines intersect at a point and they are not identical, that is the o-
-- nly point they intersect at.
intersect_at_most_one_point : Plane line point =>
  (l : line) -> (m : line) -> (a : point) -> (b : point) ->
  (l /= m) ->
  (intersects_at l m a = True) ->
  (intersects_at l m b = True) ->
  (a = b)

intersect_at_most_one_point l m a b l_not_m int_at_a int_at_b =
  same_line_same_pts
  l
  m
  a
  b
  l_not_m
  (fst (intersection_result l m a int_at_a))
  (fst (intersection_result l m b int_at_b))
  (snd (intersection_result l m a int_at_a))
  (snd (intersection_result l m b int_at_b))
```

This gives the error:

```
  |
1 | interface Plane line point where
  |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When checking type of Main.line_contains_two_points:
Type mismatch between
        Bool (Type of _ /= _)
and
        Type (Expected type)

/home/dair/scratch/hilbert.idr:68:29:
   |
68 | intersect_at_most_one_point : Plane line point =>
   |                             ^
When checking type of Main.intersect_at_most_one_point:
No such variable Plane
```

So, it seems that `/=` works only for boolean. I have been unable to find a "propositional" `/=` like:

```
data (/=) : a -> b -> Type where
```

Does a propositional not equals exist? Or am I wrong about wanting to change from boolean to propositional equality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The propositional equivalent to the boolean `a /= b` would be `a = b -> Void`. `Void` is a type with no constructors. So whenever you have a `contra : Void`, something has gone wrong. So `a = b -> Void` is to understand as: if you have an `a = b`, there is a contradiction. Usually written as `Not (a = b)`, which is just a shorthand (`Not a = a -> Void`).

You're right to change to propositional equality. You might even change your boolean properties like `contains : line -> point -> Bool` to `Contains : line -> point -> Type`. Subsequently `contains l p = True` to `Contains l p`, and `contains l p = False` to `Not (Contains l p)`.

That's a case of [boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/), i.e. with `prf : contains l p = True`, the only thing we know is that `contains l p` is `True` (and the compiler would need to take a look at `contains` to guess why it is `True`). On the other hand, with `prf : Contains l p` you have a constructed proof `prf` *why* the proposition `Contains l p` holds.